# Java JList right-click Linux (Ubuntu 12.04) no menu shown

Tags: java, linux, swing, menu, jlist

I'm adding strings to a JLabel and I want to give the possibility to edit or delete them by performing a right click and choosing the option in the context-menu.
On Windows 7 and 8 everything works as desired. But on Ubuntu 12.04 there is no menu displayed.

Here's my code for the MainView:

```
// Add context-menu to list
    _List.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
            if(SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e))
            {
                try
                {
                    Robot robot = new Robot();
                    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                }
                catch(AWTException ae)
                {}
            }

            if(e.isPopupTrigger())
            {
                doPop(e);
            }
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
        {
            if(e.isPopupTrigger())
            {
                doPop(e);
            }
        }

        private void doPop(MouseEvent e)
        {
            JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();

            // Edit Option
            if(_EditActionListener != null)
            {
                JMenuItem editItem = new JMenuItem("Edit");
                editItem.addActionListener(_EditActionListener);
                popup.add(editItem);
            }

            // Delete Option
            if(_DeleteActionListener != null)
            {
                JMenuItem deleteItem = new JMenuItem("Delete");
                deleteItem.addActionListener(_DeleteActionListener);
                popup.add(deleteItem);
            }


            popup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `isPopupTrigger()` like the example in [*Bringing Up a Popup Menu*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup), but [`setComponentPopupMenu()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setComponentPopupMenu%28javax.swing.JPopupMenu%29) may be easier.